# How to unpublish an app that offers subscriptions?

Tags: android, subscription

As stated in the [Android Developer's Documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions#Cancel), a developer must support a subscription as long as there is at least an active user:

> Important: You shouldn't remove a subscription from Google Play while
>   any user is still entitled to the content. Removing content that is
>   owed to a user will result in penalties. For more information, refer
>   to the the Cancellations section in Create a subscription.

---

> You must support a subscription as long as it has at least one active
>   user. **If a developer doesn't support subscriptions with active users,
>   the developer account will be suspended**, and the user's subscription
>   will be refunded using the developer's account.

---

The question is, how to **unpublish** an app that offers subscriptions without being penalized, so it can't be downloaded anymore?

We use the subscription model to unlock app features, and we don't offer any extra content that can be downloaded.

For "pay-to-download" apps using the LVL, is my understanding that when an app gets unpublished, the Google Servers still send the LICENSED response regardless of the app's publish state.

**I only assume** that for subscriptions would be something similar when the app in the user's device queries for active subscriptions, which would be fine, but I'm seeking a way to not allow any more downloads of the app.

Comment: why do you think unpublishing the app would penalize you? People with subscriptions will still have the app. You just need to make sure it still works for them

Comment: By the documentation wording, is unclear if unpublishing an app also means to stop supporting the subscription.

Comment: while your question is off topic here, as it is about legal things on google play store, not about application development, the users who already have your app installed won't suffer from app unpublish. Therefore it should be just fine to unpublish the app.

Comment: *is unclear if unpublishing an app also means to stop supporting the subscription* - I think it's pretty clear, you even bolded the part in the quote that covers this. You must keep supporting subscriptions with active users. It doesn't state that you can stop supporting subscriptions with active users in certain scenarios. Users paid for the product/service, you are obliged to give it to them

Comment: In our case there is no extra downloadable content. When a user subscribes, the app unlocks features which are built-in into the app. Assuming (and only guessing) that the Google Servers when queried by current app installations will still send through the Billing Library the subscriptions states, the problem we are having doubts with is that if a user for any reason uninstalls the app, then once unpublished he will not be able to download it again even if he still has an active subscription, and maybe this could be considered by Google as not supporting the subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got in contact with Google and they said there is no problem.

So as long as the subscription features within the app aren't removed and still available to paying users, is fine to unpublish it.

Here is their answer, in case is useful to other developers:

> If you choose to unpublish the app only current users will still have
>   access to the app, users are allowed unlimited reinstalls of each app
>   distributed via Google Play, so an app remains available to users that
>   have already installed it even after it has been unpublished.

---

> This includes app with in app products and subscriptions, the user
>   will continue to have access, you will need to support this as long as
>   there is an active user.